# Jenkins Pipeline Test Results Analyzer Support

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

It looks like support for test results analyzer was added to the pipeline plugin from the jira issue below.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to acutally implement the plugin using a pipeline script.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30522

Regardless of the jira issue, how can I run the test results analyzer through my pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

When you add test reports to your pipeline script this works automatically. The "Test Results Analyzer" button shows up right away for jobs that have tests, including those that use the pipeline plugin.

For example when using the standard "junit" report plugin like this, it should work out of the box:

```
    stage('Unit tests') {
        steps {
            sh 'unit-tests.sh'
        }

        post {
            always {
                junit 'path/to/report.xml'
            }
        }
    }
```